# ValueError invalid literal error with Python Multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, scipy, ipython, anaconda, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that i'm trying to run in parallel. The function is of the form

```
def parallelFunc(curUser):
    if curUser in neighbors.getUsers(): #neighbors is a global object of a class
        userData = createData.createData(inpMat1,inpMat2,inpMat3, neighbors.getNeighbors(curUser) )

    #inpMatX are numpy arrays/scipy sparse arrays/lists with global scope

        return userData # tried returning a double value too, get the same error

    else:
        return 0



pp = Pool(4) # tried with different values
ret = pp.map(parallelFunc, userList)
```

When I try running this, I get the following error

```
ValueError: invalud literal for float(): 1.235443508738e
```

The error is in multiprocessing/pool.pyc . I'm doing this in an IPython notebook. Any ideas as to why this would happen?

Stack Trace :

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-2731048b72e2> in <module>()
      3 
      4 #st = time.time()
----> 5 ret = pp.map(parallelFunc, userList)
      6 #ft = time.time()
      7 

/opt/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    249         '''
    250         assert self._state == RUN
--> 251         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    252 
    253     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):

/opt/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
    565             return self._value
    566         else:
--> 567             raise self._value
    568 
    569     def _set(self, i, obj):

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.34716296703.978260894942e+06
```

Comment: It looks like you're doing `float(some_string)` and the value of `some_string` is `'1.235443508738e'`

Comment: Don't have context for what `createData` does. Have you tried running the `parallelFunc` function without multiprocessing? Also, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: It runs fine without multiprocessing.

Comment: Can you create a complete, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem?  An  MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that could be copied and run would make it much easier to help you debug this.